# Merge multiple arrays, unknown length generated from a map

Tags: javascript

I have this starting array:

```js
const data = [
  {
    roles: [
      {
        name: "one",
      },
      {
        name: "two",
      },
    ],
    name: "Alfa",
  },
  {
    roles: [
      {
        name: "three",
      },
    ],
    name: "Bravo",
  },
  {
    name: "Charlie",
  },
];
```

I need to create an object for every name. If a name has more than one role, one item for name.

So, with the example, I need this array:

```js
[
  { name: "Alfa", role: "one" },
  { name: "Alfa", role: "two" },
  { name: "Bravo", role: "three" },
  { name: "Charlie" }
];
```

This is the function that I wrote:

```js
const cleanRoles = (data) => {
  const roles = data.map((person) => {
    if (Array.isArray(person.roles) && person.roles.length > 0) {
      return person.roles.map((role) => {
        return {
          name: person.name,
          role: role.name,
        };
      });
    }
    return {
      name: person.name,
    };
  });
  return roles;
};
```

But I get

```js
[
  [
    { name: "Alfa", role: "one" },
    { name: "Alfa", role: "two" },
  ],
  [{ name: "Bravo", role: "three" }],
  { name: "Charlie" },
];
```

How can I refactor my function to get what I need?

Comment: Use `data.flatMap` on your outer loop so that the inner arrays get concatenated together.

Comment: You want an array of objects, so clearly a map of a map (array of _arrays_ of objects) isn't the right structure.

Comment: IMO, the issue with your function is that it’s returning an array of arrays for the roles, and a single object for the people without roles. You can flatten the array using the Array.prototype.flat() method or you can use Array.prototype.reduce() to avoid creating nested arrays

Comment: btw you can do a flat() on your implementation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the data with mapping roles to new array items. Avoid `.flatMap()` since it's slower than reducing:

```js
const result = data.reduce((r, {name, roles}) => 
  (roles?.length ? roles.forEach(({name: role}) => r.push({name, role})) : r.push({name}), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      roles: [{
          name: "one",
        },
        {
          name: "two",
        },
      ],
      name: "Alfa",
    },
    {
      roles: [{
        name: "three",
      },],
      name: "Bravo",
    },
    {
      name: "Charlie",
    },
  ];
</script>
```

A generic solution with any number of properties:

```js
const result = data.reduce((r, {roles, ...user}) => 
  (roles?.length ? roles.forEach(({name: role}) => r.push({...user, role})) : r.push(user), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      roles: [{
          name: "one",
        },
        {
          name: "two",
        },
      ],
      name: "Alfa",
    },
    {
      roles: [{
        name: "three",
      },],
      name: "Bravo",
    },
    {
      name: "Charlie",
    },
  ];
</script>
```

```
` Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
-----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander                  1.0x  |   31   34   35   38   44
Mister Jojo                1.6x  |   49   49   51   52   56
Robin De Schepper         11.7x  |  363  369  374  385  393
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000000">

      const data = [{
          roles: [{
              name: "one",
            },
            {
              name: "two",
            },
          ],
          name: "Alfa",
        },
        {
          roles: [{
            name: "three",
          },],
          name: "Bravo",
        },
        {
          name: "Charlie",
        },
      ];
      
// @benchmark Mister Jojo      
data.reduce( (acc, {roles,name},i ) =>
  {
  if (Array.isArray(roles) && roles.length)
roles.forEach(({name:role}) => acc.push({name,role}));
  else
acc.push({name});
  return acc;
  },[]);    
      
// @benchmark Robin De Schepper      
data.flatMap((person) => {
    if (Array.isArray(person.roles) && person.roles.length > 0) {
      return person.roles.map((role) => {
        return {
          name: person.name,
          role: role.name,
        };
      });
    }
    return {
      name: person.name,
    };
  });      
      

// @benchmark Alexander
data.reduce((r, {name, roles}) => 
      (roles?.length ? roles.forEach(({name: role}) => r.push({name, role})) : r.push({name}), r), []);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan i try to safe every milli/microsecond. in total all the savings could lead to better UX on budget mobile devices for example

Comment: @MisterJojo sorry, man, will fix... 

Comment: @MisterJojo a typo, should be Rabbit )

Comment: @MisterJojo mistaken with https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2584384/

Comment: @mplungjan  updated the benchmark

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` does what `map` does, but expects arrays as return values and  concatenates those together into 1 large array as output:

```js
const cleanRoles = (data) =>
  data.flatMap((person) => {
    if (Array.isArray(person.roles) && person.roles.length > 0) {
      return person.roles.map((role) => {
        return {
          name: person.name,
          role: role.name,
        };
      });
    }
    return {
      name: person.name,
    };
  });
console.log(cleanRoles(data));
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      roles: [{
          name: "one",
        },
        {
          name: "two",
        },
      ],
      name: "Alfa",
    },
    {
      roles: [{
        name: "three",
      }, ],
      name: "Bravo",
    },
    {
      name: "Charlie",
    },
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: I added more certainty to the introduction of my code only answer, do you like it better now? ;)

Comment: Now I do.......

Answer (score 0):

a reduce, a forEach, and easy to read code... (right?)

```js
const data = 
  [ { roles : [ { name: 'one' } , { name: 'two' } ] 
    , name  : 'Alfa'
    } 
  , { roles : [ { name: 'three' } ] 
    , name  : 'Bravo'
    } 
  , { name  : 'Charlie' } 
  ];

const result = data.reduce( (acc, {roles,name}) =>
  {
  if (Array.isArray(roles) && roles.length)
    roles.forEach(({name:role}) => acc.push({name,role}));
  else
    acc.push({name});
  return acc;
  },[]);

console.log( result );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper    { max-height: 100% !important;top: 0; }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important;           }
```

Comment: if roles is an empty array, it will fail

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev right, I have updated may answer..

Comment: nice one!......

Answer (score 0):

If you swap around the `name` and `roles` properties in each object and write it out more uniformly, you could make much more sense of what's going on. I rearranged your data structure below to make the data appear easier to read.

You could simplify this to the following: Map each item in the array to an object with a `name` and a `role` (only if the item has `roles`).

```js
const data = [{
  name: "Alfa",        /* 1. name = Alfa      */
  roles: [
    { name: "one" },   /*    - role = one     */
    { name: "two" }    /*    - role = two     */
  ]
}, {
  name: "Bravo",       /* 2. name = Bravo     */
  roles: [
    { name: "three" }  /*    - role = three   */
  ]
}, {
  name: "Charlie"      /* 3. name = Charlie   */
}];

const cleanRoles = (data) =>
  data.flatMap(({ name, roles }) =>
    roles?.length
      ? roles.map(({ name: role }) => ({ name, role }))
      : { name });

console.log(cleanRoles(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This is identical to [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77127314/295783)

Comment: Cannot edit the starting object. It comes from an API.

Comment: @sineverba I did not edit your data structure. I rearranged it for readability. Just to demonstrate how things are laid out.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl but it is still identical to my first example